# Manifolds: Showing a curve is given locally by a function $\phi_1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, plane-curves

*Image link at bottom* I'm not sure how to go about showing that $y=\phi_1(x)$ gives the curve $4y^3-3y-x=0$ locally. I may be able to show that $DF(a) = D\phi_1(a)$, but that doesn't prove it over the whole domain. How do I approach this? Specifically, what must I show for a clear proof?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5sgW.jpg

Edit: It may not have been clear that I meant $a$ to be a single arbitrary point, not all $a ∈ ℝ$.  $\phi_1(x)={1\over2}((x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{1/3}+(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^{-1/3})$ for $x>1$.

Comment: You could start by proving that $y=\phi_1(x)$ satisfies the equation you've been given, $4y^3-3y-x=0$.  It's kind of a groady computation, I agree, but if you chug away and check your work with Wolfram Alpha (bit by bit), you should be able to do it.